# How do I nest attribute selector under :host-context?

Tags: css, css-selectors, less, shadow-dom

Using LESS pre-processor along with shadow-dom for theming support of individual components. I have also attempted nesting `:host-context` and `:host` selectors to no avail.

```
:host-context(.dark) {
  @import (multiple) 'variables/dark-theme';
  .dropdown;
}

:host-context(.light) {
  @import (multiple) 'variables/light-theme';
  .dropdown;
}

.dropdown() {
  //some component styles here

  &:disabled {
    background-color: @disabled-bg;
    color: @disabled-color;

    .dropDownListSelect {
      cursor: not-allowed;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a result of my own ignorance with Shadow-DOM as it is still somewhat new to me. I was able to accomplish this by using the `&:host` selector.

```
:host-context(.dark) {
  @import (multiple) 'variables/dark-theme';
  .dropdown;
}

:host-context(.light) {
  @import (multiple) 'variables/light-theme';
  .dropdown;
}

.dropdown() {
  //some component styles here

  &:host([disabled]) {
    background-color: @disabled-bg;
    color: @disabled-color;

    .dropDownListSelect {
      cursor: not-allowed;
    }
  }
}
```